# Does uncorrupted, unhallowed ground provide any advantages?

Tags: terraria

After a world enters hardmode, corruption and hallows spread relatively quickly throughout the land, bringing tougher enemies and better rewards. Does the spread of these biomes create disadvantages for the player, such as certain items becoming unavailable? Is there a reason to want to have vanilla biomes in your world?

Comment: I like the music in the Forest biome =)

Comment: @BBz as good a reason as any.

Comment: @BBz Ya, I'd say that's the only reason you'd want to stay in an unhallowed area, I like to stay in Hallowed areas because it soooo prettyyyyyyyyy. And a good place to farm Pixie Dust/Gel/Unicorn Horns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I'm going to be cataloguing my findings here, don't hesitate to post your own answers.**

Letting the ocean become hallowed/corrupted will make corrupt/hallow desert enemies spawn instead of ocean enemies, making the following items unobtainable: Shark Fin, Diving Helmet, Coral; their products will also be unobtainable: Megashark, Neptune's shell, waterwalking potion, hunter potion, diving gear, gills potion.

Comment: If your ocean does get corrupted/hallowed, you can always build a new one above it and pump all the water up. You'll want to line the bottom with sand, and make sure that none of the corruption spitters can hit it.

Comment: Video game logic: drat, my ocean got corrupted.  I'll just BUILD ANOTHER ONE ABOVE IT

Comment: Couldn't you also just build a base of stone at the edge of the map beneath the water, add sand, and basically build a mini-ocean on the surface of the ocean?  Or would that be corrupted too?

Answer (score 4):

**I like the music in the Forest biome =)**

---

It's not a real advantage, but it's a big part of my gaming experience. And people seem to agree with me in the comments haha

Answer (score 3):

One of the big advantages of having normal biomes in a hardmode game is the difficulty: the hallow and corruption biomes spawn much stronger monsters than the pre-hardmode biomes do.  For that reason, most people recommend that you build your home base in one such biome.

Apart from that, any time you prevent a certain type of monster from spawning, you're losing that monster's drops; you're also losing the blocks that normally make up that biome.  This means you could even potentially lose all the regular stone in your world, having it all turned into pearlstone and ebonstone.

In a large world it takes a *long* time for the corruption and hallow to take over the world, even in hardmode-- but if one of the biomes starts encroaching on your home base or eating up your favorite farming ground for enemy/block/herb x, you might want to look into cutting it off.

Comment: While it's kind of a pain if you need a lot, vile powder and purification powder can revert blocks to their original type.

Comment: That's true, I suppose I should have added that none of these changes are completely irreversible; you can always alter your world to suit your needs later.  That being said, powders can get really expensive really quickly, so if your world got overrun by a biome you didn't want, it may be best to either edit the biome out with modding software or move to a new world :P